# How to access Factorio technology list

Tags: factorio

So I just built a lab (laboratory) in Factorio and I got a list of technologies. I selected one and it disappeared. I wanted to change my mind and select a new one but I am unable to click the lab to open the tech tree. How do I get back to the list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even though you need the lab to research new technologies you don't open the tech tree from the lab. You have to press <kbd>T</kbd> to start new research.

Comment: By the way: Changing technologies is usually not advisable, because it resets the progress of the currently researched technology, wasting all the science packs which were invested into it.

Comment: @Philipp That's no longer true. Progress is now saved for each technology.